# Error in Nominatim - GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, nominatim

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "geo2.py", line 8, in <module> location = geolocator.geocode(lokacija, timeout=5)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geopy/geocoders/osm.py", line
192, in geocode self._call_geocoder(url, timeout=timeout), exactly_one
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line
147, in _call_geocoder
raise ERROR_CODE_MAP[code](message) geopy.exc.GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Worked fine till yesterday, now cannot start it.

Did anyone saw this?

Comment: Are you sure the credential used are correct? Use DEBUG for log levels and check the errors again. The [docs say](https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.9.1/#geopy.exc.GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges), `The remote geocoding service refused to fulfill a request using the account credentials given.`

Comment: Check the related GeocoderInsufficientPrivileges [GitHub issue](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/112). Use the latest Nominatim version and check if it works.

Comment: Started working 3 hours ago

Comment: How did it work? What solved your issue?

Comment: Did nothing, just started working again

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version of Nomination. Check this git hub link for the issue.

https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/112